# How to determine if Console is allocated in a winform application?

Tags: c#, winforms, console

I'm developing a Windows Forms Application. At the startup I can choose if I want to show the console too or only the main form. This is achieved via the

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern int AllocConsole();
```

command. I can even dispose it via the

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern int FreeConsole();
```

command.
How can I determine at runtime if the console is disposed or not?

Comment: Wrap the call to `AllocConsole()` in a method call and set a flag?

Comment: There's probably a better way, but maybe checking [`GetConsoleWindow()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/apps/ms683175(v=vs.90)?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#MainContent) can give you that information (returns `NULL` if no console is attached to the process).

Comment: `public void AllocateConsole() { AllocConsole(); consoleAllocated = true; }`?